# how to group by dataview in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable, dataview

I want to use group by on data view with applying a filter.

```
    SELECT xAccID,xAccName,xProdID,xProdName,
xPrice,

SUM(xQuan) AS xxQuan,xDate,SUM(xCarCount) AS xxCarCount FROM
                        (
                            (SELECT 
                        `FatoraDate` AS xDate,
                        `FatoraReso` AS xAccID,
                        `AccName` AS xAccName,
                        `FatoraProduct` AS xProdID,
                        CONCAT(`CategoryName`,' ',`ProductName`) AS xProdName,
                        `FatoraPurPrice` AS xPrice,
                        SUM(`FatoraQuan`) AS xQuan,
                        COUNT(`FatoraReso`) AS xCarCount
                        FROM tblfatora
                        INNER JOIN tblaccounts
                        ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraReso
                        INNER JOIN tblproducts
                        ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora.FatoraProduct
                        INNER JOIN tblcategories
                        ON tblcategories.CategoryID = tblproducts.ProductCategory
                        GROUP BY xAccID,xAccName,xDate,xProdID,xPrice
                        ORDER BY xDate,xAccID,xProdID)

                        UNION ALL

                        (SELECT 
                        `FatoraDate` AS xDate,
                        `FatoraCustomer` AS xAccID,
                        `AccName` AS xAccName,
                        `FatoraProduct` AS xProdID,
                        CONCAT(`CategoryName`,' ',`ProductName`) AS xProdName,
                        `FatoraSalePrice` AS xPrice,
                        SUM(`FatoraQuan`) AS xQuan,
                         COUNT(`FatoraCustomer`) AS xCarCount
                        FROM tblfatora
                        INNER JOIN tblaccounts
                        ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraCustomer
                        INNER JOIN tblproducts
                        ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora.FatoraProduct
                         INNER JOIN tblcategories
                        ON tblcategories.CategoryID = tblproducts.ProductCategory
                        GROUP BY xAccID,xAccName,xDate,xProdID,xPrice
                        ORDER BY xDate,xAccID,xProdID
                        )) tbl1
                        GROUP BY xDate,xAccID,xAccName,xProdID,xProdName,xPrice  
                        ORDER BY `tbl1`.`xAccName` ASC
```

I fill MyVar_Dt_Quan on loading and I prepre the filter:

```
MyPubVar_Sort = "xProdID,xPrice"
        MyPubVar_Filter = ""
        MyPubVar_Filter = " xAccID = " & xAccID & " 
                            AND
                            (xDate >= '" & xDate1 & "' AND xDate <= '" & xDate2 & "') "

        MyVar_Dv_Quan = MyVar_Dt_Quan.DefaultView
        MyVar_Dv_Quan.RowFilter = MyPubVar_Filter

        Dim fruitGroups = MyVar_Dv_Quan.ToTable.AsEnumerable().
                GroupBy(Function(row) New With {
                    Key .xProdID = row.Field(Of Double)("xProdID"),
                    Key .xPrice = row.Field(Of Double)("xPrice")
                })


        Dim tableResult = MyVar_Dv_Quan.ToTable.Clone()
        For Each grp In fruitGroups
            tableResult.Rows.Add(grp.Key.xProdID,
                                 grp.Key.xPrice,
                                 grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Double)("xxQuan")))
        Next

        Me.Dgv2.DataSource = tableResult
```

I want to GroupBy xProdID and xPrice and the filter is (xAccID = ? and (xDate <= ?? and >= ??)) and get the sum of xQuan and sum of xCarCount for the grouping by.
how can I apply that?

Comment: What relevance does VB.NET have to this? Please add some VB.NET code

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated again

Comment: Look like you're only missing a `, grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Double)("xCarCount"))` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard it gives me an error: "specified cast is not valid"

Comment: Is xCarCount an integer? `, grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("xCarCount"))`

Comment: @CaiusJard SUM(`FatoraQuan`) AS xQuan (Double), and COUNT(`FatoraReso`) AS xCarCount should be integer

Comment: Was the code giving the error before?

Comment: @CaiusJard {Dim tableResult = MyVar_Dv_Quan.ToTable.Clone()
            For Each grp In fruitGroups
                tableResult.Rows.Add(grp.Key.xProdID,
                                     grp.Key.xPrice,
                                     grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Double)("xxQuan")),
                                     grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("xCarCount")))
            Next}  it gives me the same error

Comment: But was it giving the error before you added xCarCount?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes..

Comment: On which line did it crash?

Comment: @CaiusJard the 6th line (System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.')

Comment: It's a little hard to follow your post. I used xCarCount because I thought you were doing the sum locally and had stripped out the part of your sql that sums xCarCount and aliases it as xxCarCount. It seems like I assumed too much. Your column is called xxCarCount...

Comment: @CaiusJard I correct to xxcarcount and it's giving me "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: I use a mobile phone, it squashes the post up and wraps the text. I'm certain "the sixth line" is different for you compared to what I see. Give the whole line of code that throws the error please, not a numerical reference that is varying for each of us

Comment: @CaiusJard  grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("xxCarCount"))

Comment: Not sure what to suggest there; is xxCarCount truly a genuine integer type column, not double or nullable int etc?  PAuse the code in the debugger and in the immediate window run `tableResult.Columns("xxCarCount").DataType` and see what it says the type of the column is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyPubVar_Sort = "xProdID,xPrice"
        MyPubVar_Filter = ""
        MyPubVar_Filter = " xAccID = " & xAccID & " 
                            AND
                            (xDate >= '" & xDate1 & "' AND xDate <= '" & xDate2 & "') "

        MyVar_Dv_Quan = MyVar_Dt_Quan.DefaultView
        MyVar_Dv_Quan.RowFilter = MyPubVar_Filter

        Dim fruitGroups = MyVar_Dv_Quan.ToTable.AsEnumerable().
                    GroupBy(Function(row) New With {
                    Key .xAccID = row.Field(Of Int32)("xAccID"),
                    Key .xAccName = row.Field(Of String)("xAccName"),
                    Key .xProdID = row.Field(Of Int32)("xProdID"),
                    Key .xProdName = row.Field(Of String)("xProdName"),
                    Key .xPrice = row.Field(Of Double)("xPrice")
                    })


        Dim tableResult = MyVar_Dv_Quan.ToTable.Clone()
        For Each grp In fruitGroups
            tableResult.Rows.Add(
                                    grp.Key.xAccID,
                                    grp.Key.xAccName,
                                    grp.Key.xProdID,
                                    grp.Key.xProdName,
                                    grp.Key.xPrice,
                                    grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Double)("xxQuan")),
                                    grp.Max(Function(row) row.Field(Of Date)("xDate")),
                                    grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Object)("xxCarCount")))
        Next

        Me.Dgv2.DataSource = tableResult
```